# Jmeter BeanShell - Access Response Data - Beanshell error?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have this code in my Beanshell Post Processor

```
String line;
String[] words;

line = SampleResult.getResponseMessage(); log.info(msg);

words  = line.split("*");

log.info("Here We are"); 

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  log.info(words[i]);
 }
```

This is the error I'm getting

> 2017/02/21 14:23:31 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error
>   invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: 
>   `String line; String[] words;  line =
>   SampleResult.getResponseMessage(); log.inf . . . '' : Attempt to
>   resolve method: getResponseMessage() on undefined variable or class
>   name: SampleResult  2017/02/21 14:23:31 WARN  -
>   jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script
>   org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:` String line; String[]
>   words;  line = SampleResult.getResponseMessage(); log.inf . . . '' :
>   Attempt to resolve method: getResponseMessage() on undefined variable
>   or class name: SampleResult

Comment: Where are you getting `SampleResult` from? because if you read the error its mor or less saying " I dont know what `SampleResult` is."

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, to get rid of the error, you need to replace `SampleResult` with `prev`.

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult

([source](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor))

So to resolve exception:

```
line = prev.getResponseMessage(); 
log.info(line);
```

You can always see the list of variables objects gives you in the object itself:

[image]

However if I understand correctly you want to get **data** and not **response message** from the sampler. So you may want to use `getResponseDataAsString()` instead of `getResponseMessage()`

So all together:

```
line = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); 
log.info(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. SampleResult is something you can use this way
2. ResponseMessage != Response Body

So use one of the following approaches

- `line = new String(data);`
- `line = prev.getResponseDataAsString();`
- `line = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString());`

Where:

- `data` is a [byte array](http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string/) containing binary representation of parent Sampler response data
- `prev` is a shorthand to current [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance
- `ctx` - stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

Also consider using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of Beanshell as Groovy is more Java-compatible, performs better and has nice language features which will make your code look and work better. See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details.